# In R how to merge a list

Tags: r

I have a list

```
$true
[1] 0

$false
[1] 183

$false
[1] 0

$true
[1] 110
```

I need to remove the elements that are repeated and zeroed.

Ideally I'd sum all the elements that have the same name, but considering they are zeroes I can just exclude them, to have something like this:

```
$false
[1] 183

$true
[1] 110
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your example data
the.list <- list(
  true = 0,
  false = 183,
  false = 0,
  true = 110
)

# convert the list to a simpler named vector
list.collapsed <- unlist(the.list)

# re-split into a list of vectors, one per unique name in the original list
list.split <- split(list.collapsed, names(list.collapsed))

# sum each label's elements
list.condensed <- lapply(list.split, sum)

$false
[1] 183

$true
[1] 110
```

As you say, the elements you want to "collapse" are all 0 and could also be filtered out various ways, but this method will sum the elements as you wanted originally.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `tapply()` if we `unlist` the list then use the list names as the groups.

```
tapply(unlist(x), names(x), sum, simplify = FALSE)
# $false
# [1] 183
#
# $true
# [1] 110
```

If it's not necessary to get a list result, we can drop `simplify`.

```
tapply(unlist(x), names(x), sum)
# false  true 
#   183   110
```

where `x` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the elements that are 0's with

```
library(purrr)
keep(lst, ~ .x != 0)
#$false
#[1] 183

#$true
#[1] 110
```

Or with `base R`

```
lst[unlist(lst)!=0]
```

---

Or with `discard`

```
discard(lst, ~ !.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Respectively by removing 0s and by summing, all in base R:

```
l[sapply(l,`!=`,0)] # or more robust: l[!sapply(l,identical,0)]
# $false
# [1] 183
# 
# $true
# [1] 110

setNames(
  lapply(unique(names(l)),
         function(x) sum(unlist(l[names(l)==x]))),
  unique(names(l)))
# $true
# [1] 110
# 
# $false
# [1] 183
```